# Shiv'a Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a year that has 2 Adar's and Cheshvan and Kislaiv are K'Sidran (29 days / 30 days) there is a total of 207 days from Tishrei to the end of Adar Bais.

Answer (score 2):

> The Tzemach Tzedek related: The Baal
>   Shem Tov was very fond of light, and
>   said, "*Or* ('light') is the numerical
>   equivalent of *raz* ('secret') [Tikunei
>   Zohar 19; Zohar III, p. 28b]. Whoever
>   knows the 'secret' contained in every
>   thing can bring illumination."

- where "or" and "raz" both equal 207.

(Hayom Yom, entry for 6 Elul)

Answer (score 2):

There are 207 sins for which one can get lashes. Source: [*Rambam*, *Sanhedrin* 19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e119n.htm).

Answer (score 1):

207 years after Yitzchok Avinu was born, Yaakov Avinu passed away in Mitzrayim.